# Feeding webpage data via remote Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to operate two servers.

1. MVC Web API service.
2. MVC Web application.

The idea is that the web application renders a page filled with javascript requests, which populate the actual data from the remote API service. The web application will never itself touch the database, or the API service (besides setting up authorisation tokens initially).

What is the best way to achieve this?

So far I've been using `JQuery` `AJAX` requests, attempting to use `JSONP`. However I always get "x was not called" exceptions.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(ViewBag.API)api/customer',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: function (data) {
            debugger;
            // code to load to ko
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    });
```

Also the `jsonpCallback` function is called before the request is sent, so I assume its actually trying to call a function to generate a string? If I reform this request:

```
    window.success = function (data) {
        debugger;
        // code to load to ko
    };
```

... with jsonpCallback being "success", I still get the same error (but the success method is never called.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: I've gotten started on the right course from this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631685/JSONP-in-ASP-NET-Web-API-Quick-Get-Started

Added the formatter, and replaced jsonCallback with success, like a normal ajax. However this only seems to work for `get`. I cannot `delete` or `update`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you get it to work using the $.getJSON method?

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  //handle response
});
```

Have you fired up developer tools in IE and watched the network traffic to see precisely what is being sent and returned?

Comment: I get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` exceptions when I try to use `getJSON`. Hence trying to use jsonp. Also I want to use CRUD operations for the Web API (so need get, post, put, delete, which I don't see the option for anywhere but `$.ajax`.